# How to invert charts in Grafana so smaller values are higher on the Y-Axis

Tags: grafana

I am wondering if it is possible to invert the Y-Axis in Grafana chart pannels. 1 should become highest and 100 be on the base line. The higher the better so 1 should be on top. Inverted. Is this possible? I tried negative values from -100 to 1 but that hack does not seem to work.

Comment: How did negating the value behave for you? It should have worked. You can set the maximum value of your Y axis to 0 so it will fix the zero line to the top instead of floating in the middle of the chart.

Comment: Actually 0 would be the worst value, while 1 is the best, 2 second best until 100 which is the worst in this set of 1-100. That is the first problem, Grafana shows 0 line despite 1 beening set to max. Second thing is the minus sign on the Y-Axis which is misleading, do you know if this can be removed somehow?